# New lines not distributed evenly when writing to multiple files

Tags: java, io

I am trying to make a program that receives an input file of a series of numbers (in_#.txt) separated by new lines, and sorts them by parity into two separate files (even.txt and odd.txt). The files are passed in through the command line. Here is an example input file:

in_1.txt:

```
5
11
22
33
44
55
```

The desired output files would be as follows:

even.txt:

```
22
44
```

odd.txt:

```
5
11
33
55
```

However, something seems to be going wrong with the new lines in my code. Here are the actual output files:

even.txt:

```
22

44
```

odd.txt:

```
5113355
```

Finally, here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class MySolution {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {  
      if(args.length > 0) {
          FileInputStream in = null;
          FileOutputStream even = null;
          FileOutputStream odd = null;

          try {
              in = new FileInputStream(new File(args[0]));
              even = new FileOutputStream(new File(args[1]));
              odd = new FileOutputStream(new File(args[2]));
              
              int c;
              while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                 if ((c%2) == 0) {
                     even.write(c);
                 } else {
                     odd.write(c);
                 }
              }
          } finally {
              if (in != null) {
                  in.close();
              }
              if (odd != null) {
                  odd.close();
              }
              if (even != null) {
                  even.close();
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not very experienced with file reading and writing.

Thank you very much in advance,

Ian

Comment: `in.read()` reads the file byte-by-byte. So you don't read out the numbers, but the "raw" bytes. `(in|odd).write()` also writes in bytes

Comment: Gotcha. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Use a BufferedReader with readLine. But actually the class Files provides many goodies like Files.lines.